# http request over ssh tunnel

Tags: java, ssh, jsch, ssh-tunnel

I have two server. I use first server installed tor application on it for hide my ip adress. It will be named as SSH Tunnel Server henceforth. Second server is to send http request on ssh tunnelling. And it will be named as Client Sever.
I wrote the codes below, for the purpose of above. But I can't read SSH Tunnel Server response. Where Am I doing wrong ?

```
            String user = "root";
            String password = "password";
            String host = "198.199."11.111";
            int port=22;

            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            session.setPassword(password);
            session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");



            session.connect();

            Channel channel=session.openChannel("direct-tcpip");
            ((ChannelDirectTCPIP)channel).setHost("whatismyipaddress.com");
            ((ChannelDirectTCPIP)channel).setPort(80);

            String cmd = "GET / HTTP/1.1" ;

            InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = channel.getOutputStream();
            channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
            channel.connect(10000);

            byte[] bytes = cmd.getBytes();          
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(cmd.getBytes("UTF-8"));

            int numRead;

            while ( (numRead = is.read(bytes) ) >= 0) {

                  out.write(bytes, 0, numRead);
                  System.out.println(numRead);
            }

            out.flush();

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                for (String line; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;){
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (java.io.IOException exc) {
                System.out.println(exc.toString());
            }
            channel.disconnect();
            session.disconnect();
            System.out.println();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not outputting any line terminators following the GET command. Try changing the GET string to this:

```
String cmd = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
```